# Ignore git sub-repositories and treat them as regular files

Tags: git, repository

I have a huge "main" git repository with several sub-folders, which themselves are separate git repos.

I use the main repo as a sort of incremental backup system. However, the main repo always ignores any of the sub-repos and excludes them from the commits.

Is there a way to fix this and treat them as regular directories for the purpose of tracking changes?

I imagine a good way would be to temporarily "delete" any .gitignore (except the main one) files and .git folders (except the main one), just until `git commit` finishes on the main repo. I would even be OK with tracking the .git folders as well if that'd be easier, though I guess it'd be very inefficient.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare those sub-repos as **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.

For backup purposes, that means the main rpeo will reference the url and exact sha1 of those subrepos.
But that would mean the subrepos would need to be pushed to their own remote '`origin`' repo and backed up independently: what you would record in the main rpeo is only the coherent set of git subrepos SHA1 at a given time, nothing more.

To actually backup everything (main repo and subrepos), you would need to revert to classic incremental backup softwares.